# My image is extending out of the jumbotron, how do I fit it perfectly in the jumbotron?

Tags: html, css

I have the following css & html:
The image is extending past the jumbotron, I want it to perfectly fit it in the jumbotron perfectly

```css
body {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.quote {
  font-family: lobster, monospace;
}
.jumbotron {
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="text-primary text-center">Wolverine:</h1>
    <h2 class="text-center"><em>Weapon-X</em></h2>
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://s.marketwatch.com/public/resources/MWimages/MW-FH148_LoganM_ZG_20170302111413.jpg">
    <div class="caption">The Ultimate Killing Machine</div>
    <br>
    <ul type="none">
      <li>Candian</li>
      <li>Veteran</li>
      <li>Mutant</li>
    </ul>
  <p class="quote">"I'm the best at what I do, and what I do isn't very nice"</p>
  <br>
  <p>- Logan</p>
    <h3> Read more at <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_(character)" target="blank"> at wikipedia</a></h3>
        </div>
  <p class="text-center text-danger">Authored by Pranav Reddy</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When I apply Bootstrap to your markup the image stays withing the jumbotron.

Comment: Are you sure? I tested it on Chrome, IE, Edge, different screen sizes and it looks fine and centered

Answer (score 0):

Add `.jumbotron { padding: 0}` to css.

Here is the snippet:

```css
body {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.quote {
  font-family: lobster, monospace;
}
.jumbotron {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="text-primary text-center">Wolverine:</h1>
    <h2 class="text-center"><em>Weapon-X</em></h2>
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://s.marketwatch.com/public/resources/MWimages/MW-FH148_LoganM_ZG_20170302111413.jpg">
    <div class="caption">The Ultimate Killing Machine</div>
    <br>
    <ul type="none">
      <li>Candian</li>
      <li>Veteran</li>
      <li>Mutant</li>
    </ul>
  <p class="quote">"I'm the best at what I do, and what I do isn't very nice"</p>
  <br>
  <p>- Logan</p>
    <h3> Read more at <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_(character)" target="blank"> at wikipedia</a></h3>
        </div>
  <p class="text-center text-danger">Authored by Pranav Reddy</p>
</div>
```

Or even more simple method, I assume that you are use Bootstrap, is to add jumbotron-fluid class to jumbotron div like this: `<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">`

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `background-size: 100% 100%;` to your `jumbotron`

```css
body {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.quote {
  font-family: lobster, monospace;
}
.jumbotron {background-size: 100% 100%; }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="text-primary text-center">Wolverine:</h1>
    <h2 class="text-center"><em>Weapon-X</em></h2>
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://s.marketwatch.com/public/resources/MWimages/MW-FH148_LoganM_ZG_20170302111413.jpg">
    <div class="caption">The Ultimate Killing Machine</div>
    <br>
    <ul type="none">
      <li>Candian</li>
      <li>Veteran</li>
      <li>Mutant</li>
    </ul>
  <p class="quote">"I'm the best at what I do, and what I do isn't very nice"</p>
  <br>
  <p>- Logan</p>
    <h3> Read more at <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_(character)" target="blank"> at wikipedia</a></h3>
        </div>
  <p class="text-center text-danger">Authored by Pranav Reddy</p>
</div>
```